# Write a function that for two numbers a and b returns their sum of squares a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 and (a + b) ^ 2 using pointers

Tags: c, exponentiation

My program return the wrong results. I honestly dont know where the problem is. `a==5` and `b==3`, instead of returning the correct results, they return 2 for `a ^ 2 + b ^ 2` and 10 for `(a + b) ^ 2`. Unless I am using pointers the wrong way, I do not know what is the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int a=5;
int b=3;
int c,d;
koko(&a,&b,&c,&d);
printf("Rezulat brojeva %d i %d je %d i %d",a,b,c,d);

}

int koko(int *x,int *y,int *z,int *u)
{
 *z=(*x)^2+(*y)^2;
 *u=(*x+*y)^2;
}
```

Comment: The `^` operator does not perform exponentiation in C. It is a bitwise XOR operator. To square an `int`, multiply it by itself. (Do not use the `pow` function: that is for `double` and might not behave as you think.)

Comment: BTW: using pointers for pure _input_ parameters (x and y here)  is pretty pointless.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: The point of the pointers from the student’s perspective is they are required to conform to the requirements of the assignment and get credit for it. The point of the pointers from the teacher’s perspective is they give the student exercise in a new concept.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I think passing x and y by value and the results z and u by pointer would fully fullfill the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the C syntax, the `^` character  is not implied to be used to perform exponentiation on operands. It is implied as the XOR operator used by operations on bits.

You can do the exponentiation by 2 by f.e. multiplying the respective value with itself:

```
exp2_a = a * a;       // Example.
```

Also the parameters of `int*` types for `x` and `y` in `koko()` do not need to be pointers (as soon as it isn´t a requirement for the task that all parameter types must be pointers), as we don´t need to alter the passed objects from inside of `koko()`. This makes the handle at the call to the function more convenient as we do not need to add the ampersand operator (`&`) for providing the relative addresses. Just change them to type `int`.

Furthermore,`koko()` does not return anything, so the return value should be of type `void`, not `int`.

So rather use:

```
void koko(int x, int y, int* z, int* u)
{
   *z = (x * x) + (y * y);
   *u = (x + y) * (x + y);
}
```

Next thing is you missed the declaration/prototype of `koko()` before `main()` since the function is defined after `main()` in the source code. This shall give you a compilation warning at least.

---

Here is the complete and corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void koko(int,int,int*,int*);

int main()
{
   int a=5;
   int b=3;
   int c,d;
   koko(a,b,&c,&d);
   printf("Rezulat brojeva %d i %d je %d i %d",a,b,c,d);
}

void koko(int x, int y, int* z, int* u)
{
   *z = (x * x) + (y * y);
   *u = (x + y) * (x + y);
}
```

Output:

```
Rezulat brojeva 5 i 3 je 34 i 64
```

Comment: Likely the parameter types do need to be pointers because that is a requirement of the assignment, and removing them would cause the student to lose partial or full credit for the assignment.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are right and I took the concern into the answer but unfortunately, the OP provided almost no information about the assignment (and even no reaction from his/her part takes place). "using pointers" does not say anything about if he/she is coerced to that all parameters have to be pointers - Maybe the teacher said to only use pointers to `c` and `d` and it is only his own way to design the function in that way - we just can´t know. And as long as he/she didn´t specified the requirements clearly, the according part of my answer isn´t misplaced.

Comment: I am very sorry for not giving enough information. The reason why I could not give more information because there is none, my teacher just said to solve the task at hand with pointers and nothing more.

Comment: @ile123 *"My teacher just said to solve the task at hand with pointers and nothing more."* - It´s very bad to have such loose assignment. A teacher shall give concrete requirements to a task or otherwise state where you are free (of course in a permissible measure) to use what you like to. How will anyone resolve it else? However, If s/he said you shall solve the task **with** pointers, s/he high-probably meant to use pointers to be able to modify the result-holding objects in `main()`, in your case `c` and `d` from inside of the function. I think this is more to be interpreted as a hint.

Comment: @ile123 You do not need to be sorry. :-) But at your next question, remember to be as specific and focused as possible. If you have anything to say, which could be helpful - say it. It helps us to help you. Never forget that.

Comment: I will try to add as much context as I can next time I ask a question. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The `^` operator is not for exponentiation in c.it is bitwise XOR operator, see this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C).

you can use this instead:

```
int koko(int *x,int *y,int *z,int *u)
{
 *z=((*x)*(*x))+((*y)*(*y));
 *u=(*x+*y)*(*x+*y);
}
```